# i have control upload file if file empty show message but if i file is not empty still show message

Tags: c#, asp.net, upload

//  This my CODE BEHIND
     process upload file image, filesize, no file same

```
HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
            if (hfc != null)
            {
                string cekDir = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["docLoc"], id_hazard_report);

                string PicDir;
                if (Directory.Exists(cekDir)) //check Folder avlalible or not
                {
                    PicDir = cekDir;
                }
                else
                {
                    DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(cekDir); // create Folder
                    PicDir = cekDir;
                }

                string fullname;
                string filename;

                //FileUpload FileUpload1 = (FileUpload)FormView1.FindControl("FileUpload1");
                // string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName); //Get The File Extension
```

//  this process looping file upload and this my problem

```
                for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
                {
                    HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
                    string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(hpf.FileName);

                    if (((CustomControls_DdlLocation)FormView1.Controls[0].FindControl("ddl_location1")).SelectedText.ToLower().Trim() == "kelanis")
                    {
                       // This my problem if file is empty... 
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hpf.FileName))
                        {

                            myfb._error("Upload harus isi");
                            return;

                    if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
                        {
                        ///full path name to check exist or not
                        fullname = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", PicDir, Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName.Replace(" ", "_")));
                        bool ex = File.Exists(fullname);
                        if (fileExt == (".jpg") || fileExt == (".gif") || fileExt == (".bmp") || fileExt == (".png") || fileExt == (".jpeg"))
                        {
                            if (hpf.ContentLength > 200000)/*(hpf.ContentLength > 200000)*/
                            {
                                //Session["rahmat"] = "errorLebihBesar";
                               // Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
                                //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Type.GetType("System.String"), "messagebox", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('File Tidak boleh lebih dari 200 kb');</script>");
                                continue;
                            }


                            if (ex == true)
                            {

                                string f = Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName.Replace(" ", "_"));
                                string[] a = new string[1];
                                a = f.Split('.');
                                filename = string.Format("{0}_{1}.{2}", a.GetValue(0), DateTime.Now.ToString("yymdHm"), a.GetValue(1));
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                filename = Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName.Replace(" ", "_")).ToString();

                            }

                            ///full path name to store in database with new filename
                            //string[] aa = new string[1];
                            //filename = string.Format("{0}_{1}.{2}", aa.GetValue(0), DateTime.Now.ToString("yymdHm"), aa.GetValue(1));
                            fullname = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", PicDir, filename);
                            hpf.SaveAs(fullname);
                            InsertHazardDoc(id_hazard_report, filename);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Session["rahmat"] = "errorFormat";
                            //Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
                            // FileUpload1.Focus();
                           // ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Type.GetType("System.String"), "messagebox", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('File Bukan Format Gambar');</script>");
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            //Page.DataBind();
            //myfb._success("Hazard Report Succesfully Inserted");

            Session["rahmat"] = "success";
            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            myfb._error(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Can help me? how solution in this problem. if i upload file empty is true show message error like this myfb._error("Upload harus isi");  but if i has upload file still show message error myfb._error("Upload harus isi");. i want to if has upload file continue fo succesffull

Answer (score 1):

i don't know how to use with HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
if your posting from form, u can use like this.
Need to change

```
HttpFileCollection  to System.Web.HttpFileCollectionBase and 

System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase p;
foreach (System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase item in hfc)
{
    p = item;
}
```

in client page check post method enctype exists or not

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

If your using server images choose File datatype.

Comment: ok sir but, must focus in hpf httppostfile sir, this my problem i don't know im wrong write code. i just want if hpf null show message error else no message error just do it .

Comment: if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hpf.FileName))
    {
       myfb._error("Upload harus isi");
       return;
     } --- missing brakets
                    if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)

Comment: no missing brakets sir . my problem 

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hpf.FileName)) { myfb._error("Upload harus isi"); return;

Comment: if it's not a brackets missing error , u need to change code as i mention previously. The thing is file data not holding with HttpFileCollection change the code and  test it again

Comment: before i add coding this if (((CustomControls_DdlLocation)FormView1.Controls[0].FindControl("ddl_location1")).SelectedText.ToLower().Trim() == "kelanis")
                    {
                        

                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hpf.FileName))
                        {
                            myfb._error("Upload harus isi");
                            return;}} my code else normally.

Comment: i just wanna if hpf null show message "Upload harus isi" else that continue. my problem is always show "Upload harus isi"